# triggers are not working as expected to calculate cumulative running hours

Tags: sql-server, triggers

i have one table Energies and one trigger table run hours. when any record inserted data should be updated in triggerd table.while inserting trigger it should add on the on durartion or off duration based on  reactor_off_Durartion =off/on.total on time column is not coming correct for the first value inserted.
for first record it should not add.

trigger

```
USE [EnergyMonitoringDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Energies_INSERT]    Script Date: 11/26/2019 9:43:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Energies_INSERT]
   ON  [dbo].[Energies]
   AFTER  INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

 If (SELECT reactor_off_Durartion FROM INSERTED) ='on'
 Begin
 UPDATE run_hours
   SET  latest_status = reactor_off_Durartion,last_modified=recorddatetime,
    total_ontime += (SELECT DATEDIFF(second,(select last_modified from run_hours),RecordDateTime))
   FROM inserted
    End
   Else
    UPDATE run_hours
   SET  latest_status = reactor_off_Durartion,last_modified=recorddatetime,
   total_offtime += (SELECT DATEDIFF(second,(select last_modified from run_hours),RecordDateTime))
   FROM inserted
   end
```

trigger table

```
total_ontime    total_offtime   latest_status   last_modified   status
-2563200    0   on  2019-11-26 09:00:00.000 0

total_ontime    int 
total_offtime   int 
latest_status   varchar(10) 
last_modified   datetime    
status  int 



 Energies table




     Id y_status    RecordDateTime  DeviceId    reactor_off_Durartion   b_current   r_current   y_current   b_status    r_status
6071    1   2019-11-26 09:00:00.0000000 1   on  1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only ever be a single row in inserted. Triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. Your logic needs to be set based. If you can share the table structure, some sample data and desired results we can help.

Comment: it is because you are updating the hidden "inserted" table. check out updates with joins. you'll need to join the inserted table to the original source table. http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/